# How to define a style for ul which appears automatically

Tags: css, jsf

My xhtml page contains the code

```
 <h:form id="stackForm">
      <p:orderList  id="stack"> ... </p:orderList>
 </<h:form>
```

It generates the html

```
<form id="stackForm">
     <table id="stackForm:stack"> 
        <ul class="ui-widget-content ui-orderlist-list ui-corner-all ui-sortable"><li>...</li></ul>
     </table>
</form>
```

How can I set the style for **ul**?

I’ve tried the style but with no success

```
#stackForm:stack ul {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form#stackForm table#stackForm\:stack ul{
    background-color:red;
}
```

This should work.